# Powershell - create key/value pair from CSV variable

Tags: powershell, csv, keyvaluepair

I have following CSV file:

```
link,user,password
http://1.1.1.1,user1,password1
http://2.2.2.2,user2,password2
```

Using this script i can extract values of `link,user and password` headers

```
# Constants.
$DELIM = ','
#$CSV_F = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.csv' 

# Parse keys
$keys = (gc "${CSV_F}" -TotalCount 1).Split($DELIM)
$csv = Import-CSV "${CSV_F}"
$data = @()

# Iterate through CSV to build array of hashtables.
ForEach ($r in $csv) {
    $tmp_h = @{}

    # Create hash of key-value pairs.
    ForEach($k in $keys) {
        $tmp_h[$k] = $r.($k)
    }

    # Add hash to array of hashes.
    $data += $tmp_h
}

# Display data

foreach($i in $data){

$link = $i.link

$user = $i.user

$password = $i.password

}
```

**Output:**

> http://1.1.1.1
>
> user1
>
> password1
>
> http://2.2.2.2
>
> user2
>
> password2

Because this CSV contains sensitive data i want to hide it's content.

I accomplished it in following way:

```
Protect-CmsMessage -To "*youralias@emailaddress.com*" -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.csv -OutFile C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.csv.cms
```

I also can decrypt it:

```
$CSV_F = Unprotect-CmsMessage -To "*youralias@emailaddress.com*" -Path .\1.csv.cms
```

i stored unencrypted content of 1.csv.cms file into $CSV_F variable

```
$CSV_F
link,user,password
http://1.1.1.1,user1,password1
http://2.2.2.2,user2,password2
```

How to parse $CSV_F variable to get same key:value pair as i got when parsed CSV file ?

I want to avoid storing unencrypted CSV content to file.

Desired output:

> http://1.1.1.1
>
> user1
>
> password1
>
> http://2.2.2.2
>
> user2
>
> password2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `Unprotect-CmsMessage` you are saving the contents of the file as plain text in the `$CSV_F` variable. You simply have to convert it from CSV into an object that you can work with:

```
...
$CSV_F = Unprotect-CmsMessage -To "*youralias@emailaddress.com*" -Path .\1.csv.cms

$Data = $CSV_F | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Data
```